# Solving the system of three equations $x+y=1, y+z=7, z-x=6$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

$$x+y=1\\
y+z=7\\
z-x=6$$

I found an answer, but I don't know how to show my work to get it. I must've gotten it on a fluke, because I don't know how I got there.

Can anyone explain to me how to get the answer to this problem?
And what type of problem is this called? I couldn't find any examples like it online.

Thanks.

Comment: "I don't know how to show my work to get it".... Try just writing down what you wrote in order to get the result. Or did you just guess it?

Comment: [Wiki can](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Solving_a_linear_system)

Comment: Also, the system has more than one solution. For example, $x=1, y=0, y=7$ solves the system, but so does $x=0, y=1, z=6$, and $x=-1, y=2, z=5$, and many more.

Comment: I got the first one by just working it out in my head, but I don't know how to put it on paper.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is even a way to show your work without plugging in random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a system of linear equations. You can use substitution to solve it. From the first equation, $x = 1 - y$, so substituting into the third equation we get $z - (1-y)=6$, that is, $y+z=7$. Notice that this is precisely the second equation, so that equation does not provided additional constraints on $(x,y,z)$.  So we have 2 equations and 3 unknowns, thus infinite possible solution triplets. Further substitution shows the pattern of the triplets:

$y +z = 7 \implies y = 7 - z$, and

$x+y = 1 \implies x = 1 -y = 1 - (7 - z) = z - 6$.

So, for any given $z$, the solution will look like $(z-6,7-z,z)$.